# custom CSV fields names in spring batch writer

Tags: spring-batch, export-to-csv

i want to write to a CSV file in spring batch writer, but i don't want to use the property names in my bean, i need a custom field name. is there another way to do it without using BeanWrapperFieldExtractor?

Here's my bean:

```
public class VMi {
    private String Name;
    private String OrgName;
    private String Status;
    private int CPU;
    private int RAM;
    private String IP;
}
```

i want to output the fields with the same names except for "OrgName" which i want it as "Organization->Name"

Comment: Do you mean you want different names in the header of the output file? Because the `BeanWrapperFieldExtractor` extracts values from fields based on getters and you can still use it in conjunction with a `FlatFileHeaderCallback` where you write the custom field names in the header.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write different names in the header of the output file, you can use a `FlatFileHeaderCallback`. Here is a quick example:

```
@Bean
public FlatFileItemWriter<VMi> itemWriter() {
    return new FlatFileItemWriterBuilder<VMi>()
            .resource(new FileSystemResource("vmi.csv"))
            .name("vmiWriter")
            .delimited()
            .names("Name", "OrgName", "Status", "CPU", "RAM", "IP")
            .headerCallback(writer -> writer.write("Name, Organization->Name, Status, CPU, RAM, IP"))
            .build();
}
```

This will still use the `BeanWrapperFieldExtractor` to extract values from items based on getters, but writes a different name for `OrgName` in the output file.